# Mutate taking a difference based on the criteria of different column

Tags: r

```
| weight    | Time     | Chick   | Diet    |
|-----------|----------|---------|---------|
|    42     |    0     |    1    |    1    |
|    51     |    2     |    1    |    1    |
|    59     |    4     |    1    |    1    |
|    64     |    6     |    1    |    1    |
|    76     |    8     |    1    |    1    |
|    93     |    10    |    1    |    1    |
|    106    |    12    |    1    |    1    |
|    125    |    14    |    1    |    1    |
|    149    |    16    |    1    |    1    |
|    171    |    18    |    1    |    1    |
|    199    |    20    |    1    |    1    |
|    205    |    21    |    1    |    1    |
|    40     |    0     |    2    |    1    |
|    49     |    2     |    2    |    1    |
```

I need to take the current weight and subtract the weight at time 0. Time interval resets every 12th rows. Mutate it into a WeightGain column. Please help me do this in r.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We create a grouping variable based on the occurence at Time 0, then substract 'weight' from the first 'weight'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(grp = cumsum(Time==0)) %>%
   mutate(WeightGain = weight - first(weight))
# A tibble: 24 x 6
# Groups:   grp [2]
#   weight  Time Chick  Diet   grp newweight
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
# 1     42     0     1     1     1         0
# 2     51     2     1     1     1         9
# 3     59     4     1     1     1        17
# 4     64     6     1     1     1        22
# 5     76     8     1     1     1        34
# 6     93    10     1     1     1        51
# 7    106    12     1     1     1        64
# 8    125    14     1     1     1        83
# 9    149    16     1     1     1       107
#10    171    18     1     1     1       129
# ... with 14 more rows
```